# Build a dynamic list of INSERT statement values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing a stored procedure to create a set of `DELETE` statements for an administrator to run against a database

As part of the "rollback" solution, I would like, for every row I am going to delete, to also create, separately, a corresponding `INSERT` statement so that should the person running the script wish to undo, they can simply run the insert statements against the database

My question is, if I have a table with say 8 columns (Col1..Col8), how can I extract the values in a comma separated list for all columns so that I end up with

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES (Col1value, Col2value, ...Col8value)
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following command:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ' FROM [Table]'
```

That will build a `SELECT` statement for a specific table. To build an `INSERT` statement it might look like this:

```
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [Table] (' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ') VALUES (' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', @' + name
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ')'
```

There are of course many ways to get to the `INSERT` statement, mold it for your liking.

Comment: Thanks @Michael - this gives me the column names for my INSERT statement, but how do I get the values into a comma separated list?

Comment: @Mike, I'm not sure because I don't know where the values are coming from.

Comment: good point and reading my question back, I've not explained it very well. The values are the actual values from the Table your code gets the column names from. Basically, I want to turn the results of the SELECT * into a comma separated list to insert into the "VALUES (xxx)"

Comment: @Mike, so you want the very same list of comma-delimited field names in the `VALUES` list? You do mean something more along the lines of parameterized versions right (e.g. `@Field1` instead of `[Field1]`)?

Comment: this gives me a list of "@fieldnames", but I need the actual values from the table. So if I am deleting a row that has 'A' in Col1, 'Yes' in Col2 and 'Orange' in Col3 from TableA, I need to also create an INSERT statement "INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('A', 'Yes', Orange')". The columns are unknown at runtime, so the OBJECT_ID is very useful to get the column names from your example, but I need the values in a comma separated string

Comment: @Mike, that solution is probably a bit out of scope from what I can reasonably provide at this time. That's going to require the use of a `FUNCTION` that returns the actual values for a PK. I may be able to come back and provide that solution later, but in the meantime, go down the road of building a `FUNCTION` that receives a table name and PK and then uses that first statement I gave you to execute a dynamic SQL statement. You can then comma-delimit the results of that dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for all your time Michael. Much appreciated. I think I will go down the dynamic SQL route to build the string

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for a generic solution from other experts, here's an expedient version that is appropriate if the table structure is known and stable.  This test data:-

```
create table #mytable (
    col1value varchar (50),
    col2value int,
    col3value decimal(10, 5),
    col4value date,
    col5value datetime
);

insert into #mytable values 
    (null,1,234.567,'2013-12-20','2013-01-07T17:30:24.567'),
    ('def',null,987.645,'2013-12-21','2013-01-01'),
    ('abc',17,null,'2013-12-20','2013-10-07T11:31:21.517'),
    ('jkl',2,3232.32,null,'2013-01-01 01:02:03.456'),
    ('mno',2,7.4006,'2012-07-04',null)
```

Allows this code:-

```
select 'insert into #myTable values (' +
    isnull('''' + col1value + '''','null') + ',' +
    isnull(convert(varchar(50),col2value),'null') + ',' + 
    isnull(convert(varchar(50),col3value),'null') + ',' +
    isnull('''' + convert(varchar(50),col4value) + '''','null') + ',' +
    isnull('''' + convert(varchar(50),col5value,121) + '''','null') + 
    ')'
from #mytable
```

To produce:-

```
insert into #myTable values (null,1,234.56700,'2013-12-20','2013-01-07 17:30:24.567')
insert into #myTable values ('def',null,987.64500,'2013-12-21','2013-01-01 00:00:00.000')
insert into #myTable values ('abc',17,null,'2013-12-20','2013-10-07 11:31:21.517')
insert into #myTable values ('jkl',2,3232.32000,null,'2013-01-01 01:02:03.457')
insert into #myTable values ('mno',2,7.40060,'2012-07-04',null)
```

You can protect against structure changes (to some degree) by including a column list in the `insert` statements.  Even with a column list - if someone adds a non nullable column to the table without a default value - your inserts are going to fail (unless you massage them as the schema is changed).

I would ALWAYS use a code factory to produce this sort of code (i.e. an SP that runs over the information schema - that uses the column types to build the code to serialise each type of value).

The example above only handles a few of the types that you may need to handle - but you should be able to work out how to approach all of the other types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temprory table and then insert a extra line in your procedure which will add this row to your temprory table.
When the person wants to undo just fetch the last row of the table(add a extra column with time or date while inserting) and insert this row in your main table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but my requirement is to procduce a script that can be run in isolation. So I trying to create a file that will have definitive INSERT statements in it that the user can run, so I Need to return a comma separated list of the values returned by SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using third party tools, you could use [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features)

It is a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) add-in for versions 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012.

It can do many things including: Generate insert statement for a table, view or the whole database (See the features page: [Insert statement generator](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9)).

I used it myself to do the exact same thing you're asking: create a backup for a large number of data records so we could easily roll back our changes.

Answer (score 0):

This will will work.. pass table name, column name on which you want to apply condition and pass condition. Like `exec sp_get_columns 'tbl_name', 'column_name', '100'`

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE SP_GET_COLUMNS
@TABLE_NAME varchar(256)
,@COND_COL varchar(256)
,@COND varchar(256)
AS
BEGIN            
SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) seq_no, COLUMN_NAME into #temp FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
Declare @Data AS Nvarchar(MAX) 
SELECT @Data = COALESCE(@Data + ','','',', '') + COLUMN_NAME FROM  #temp
DECLARE @query varchar(1000) = 'SELECT CONCAT(' + @Data + ') from ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + @COND_COL + ' = ''' + @COND + ''''
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (val VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO #temp2 exec(@query)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@TABLE_NAME,' VALUES(''', REPLACE(val,',',''',''') ,''')'),',''''',',NULL'),','''',',',NULL,') as Query FROM #temp2
drop Table #temp,#temp2
END
```